# Not able to write into log file using logger module

Tags: python, logging, try-except

```
ts = str(datetime.datetime.now())
log = "DIF_logfile_" + ts
logging.basicConfig(filename=log, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filemode='w')
logger = logging.getLogger()
config.read(sys.argv[1])
mode = logger.error
logger.setLevel(mode)
for tbl in table:
    try:hive_tbl = config.get(tbl, "hive_tbl")
    except:logger.error("Table doesn't exists")
    #except:print "Table doesn't exists"
```

When the tbl value passed is wrong, I'm not able to write exception to the log file, but if I print its coming in console. I'm passing tbl value from config file.

Comment: `ts = str(datetime.datetime.now())
log = "DIF_logfile_" + ts
logging.basicConfig(filename=log,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                    filemode='w')
logger = logging.getLogger()
config.read(sys.argv[1])
mode = logger.error
logger.setLevel(mode)` This is first part of the code

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51665352/edit) then put the code into your question

Comment: @U9 New users cannot edit questions, even their own. I added the code in.

Comment: @ktb I gave one vote to approve it

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

This code should not even work, these lines :

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
mode = logger.error
logger.setLevel(mode)
```

Should be like this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
mode = logging.ERROR
logger.setLevel(mode)
```

After I changed them it worked. One more mention is that be sure that these lines:

```
ts = str(datetime.datetime.now())
log = "DIF_logfile_"+ts
```

Create a valid filename, they did not on my system

Comment: No. Your code also not working. 
sorry 'mode = logger.error' was typing mistake, actually I coded 'mode =  logging.error' in my program. I'm passing the mode from config file is that a problem?, when I comment out logger.setLevel(mode) it is working,in default logging.warning mode.